# React.js: Calculate new stats after being fed existing stats and stats about votes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble with this assignment below.

When reviewing the following code, what changes might you make/suggest?

```
// utils/stats.js

export const voteStats = (votes, existingStats) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(votes)) {
    throw new Error('You must pass an array of votes to voteStats');
  }

  const ret = [];
  for (const v of votes) {
    const hash = {};
    hash.count = v.count;
    hash.userId = v.user.id;
    ret.push(hash);
  }
  for (const stat of existingStats) {
    ret.push(stat);
  }
  return ret;
};
```

```
// utils/stats-test.js

import { voteStats } from './stats';

describe('voteStats', () => {
  it('should calculate new stats after being fed existing stats and stats about votes', () => {
    expect(
      voteStats(
        [
          { count: 22, user: { id: 121 } },
          { count: 61, user: { id: 122 } },
          { count: 93, user: { id: 123 } },
        ],
        [
          { count: 11, userId: 118 },
          { count: 42, userId: 119 },
          { count: 78, userId: 120 },
        ]
      )
    ).toEqual([
      { count: 11, userId: 118 },
      { count: 42, userId: 119 },
      { count: 78, userId: 120 },
      { count: 22, userId: 121 },
      { count: 61, userId: 122 },
      { count: 78, userId: 123 },
    ]);
  });
});
```

```
// user-actions.js

import { voteStats } from './utils/stats';

export default class {
  constructor(votes = [], stats = []) {
    this.stats = voteStats(votes, stats);
  }

  render() {
    return `<ul>
      ${this.stats.map(
        stat => `<li>User ID ${stat.userId} took ${stat.count} actions</li>`
      )}
    </ul>`;
  }
}
```

I am new to Learning React and having trouble understanding what is going on with the code assignment. For me all I can see that in the //user.actions.js file it is missing

-import React, {Component} from 'react'; (missing a Class name). I could be wrong.

Comment: Did you write this code? If you wrote, you could tell us what you are trying to achieve with this code. Or, what are you expecting its answer to be like? I can create a ReactJS component which would render a list of `User ID {stat.userId} took {stat.count} actions`. There are syntax errors in your React component.

Comment: I did not write this code. This a class assignment, I am basically trying to render it to the screen and trying to figure out the errors.

Comment: See my answer. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

To create a React Component that renders a list from [state data](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html), you need to:

1. **Fix the [component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)**: Give it a name (in upper CamelCase) that extends `React.Component`. You may also try functional component.
2. **Initialize** the `stats` in **state** data in constructor.
3. **Render** the [list](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) using [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) in `return` block.

**An example:**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { voteStats } from './utils/stats';

const votes = [{ count: 22, user: { id: 121 } }, { count: 61, user: { id: 122 } }, { count: 93, user: { id: 123 } },];
const existingVotes = [{ count: 11, userId: 118 }, { count: 42, userId: 119 }, { count: 78, userId: 120 },];

export default class UserActions extends Component { // 1
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stats: voteStats(votes, existingVotes), // 2
    };
  }

  render() {
    // 3
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.stats.map((stat) => (
          <li key={stat.userId}>
            User ID {stat.userId} took {stat.count} actions
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```